# generalize function to delete entity from multiple IList in single class

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin, realm, realm-list

i have a class that has multiple lists i.e.`City` , `State` and `Country` as a member of that class , now i want to make a generalize function where in 
user can pass the id of country or state or city , it will delete that specific record. I have common out the elements i.e. id by implementing `IEntity` interface to each class so that i can delete specific city , country and state based on `id` so that i can perform `deleteDataFromNotification<City>("23323")`

But the issue over here is `IList`. Is there a way to create such a function that accepts `MatserInfo` and automatically get the required list and delete off the entity.

something like , where getEntityList fetch the list automatically

```
var data = realm.All<MasterInfo>().getEntityList().Where(d => d.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

following is my code

```
void deleteData<T>(String id) where T : RealmObject, IEntity{

            Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();

            try
            {
                var data = realm.All<T>().Where(d => d.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

                realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>
                {

                    if (data != null)
                        tempRealm.Remove(data);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("Exception " + e.Message);
            }

}

public class MasterInfo : RealmObject {

    [JsonProperty("listCityMaster", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<City> cityList { get; }

    [JsonProperty("listStateMaster", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<State> stateList { get; }

    [JsonProperty("listCountryMaster", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<Country> countryList { get; }

}

public  class Country : RealmObject,IEntity
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}

public class State : RealmObject,IEntity
{

    public String countryId { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }

}

 public class City : RealmObject,IEntity
{

    public String countryId { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String stateId { get; set; }


}

 public interface IEntity
{

     String id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use reflection to find property of `MasterInfo` which returns `IList<T>` for given type `T`?

Comment: are IDs exclusive between your list sets { cityList, stateList, countryList }? You seem to be describing a search through all those lists by id (not type), and therefore you can't have the same id in different lists for that to work.

Comment: I want to search through by type and then ID

Comment: @Evk can you please give us an example ?

Comment: Sure, if answer below does not already satisfy your needs.

Comment: Just want to point out two issues with the code you posted for `deleteData` - you're not awaiting the `WriteAsync` call which means you won't get the the exception it will throw and it will throw an exception because you're passing objects between threads. You should just use `Write` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example shown, you could implement `GetEntityList<T>` in the MasterInfo class as follows.  As written, this will return null, not an error, if called with a non-matching type.

```
public IList<T> GetEntityList<T>()
{
    return (cityList as IList<T>) ?? (stateList as IList<T>) ?? (countryList as IList<T>);
}
```

Edit: Show a more dynamic way.

This version creates a list of properties that implement IList and caches the property getters in a static dictionary variable.  When you call GetEntityList, it uses the appropriate getter to return the matching list.

The reflection to get the matching properties is run once when your application first executes this code.  The reflection to get the property value is executed whenever you call GetEntityList.

```
static Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo> DictionaryOfILists = typeof(MasterInfo)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(v => v.PropertyType.IsGenericType && v.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
    .ToDictionary(v => v.PropertyType, v => v);

public IList<T> GetEntityList<T>()
{
    return DictionaryOfILists[typeof(IList<T>)].GetValue(this) as IList<T>;
}
```

Comment: Ohh okay ,so in future if my `MasterInfo` class add one more list i have to update this function as well ?

Comment: Is there any more dynamic way ?

Comment: Yes.  There is, but it adds a lot of complexity to the method.  I will post an update shortly.

Comment: i have replaced two things as it was not supported and after that it worked `GetProperties` by `GetRuntimeProperties()` , `IsGenericType ` by `IsConstructedGenericType`. does this approach slow down the searching ?

Comment: No problem.  Just a difference in reflection from the C# executable environment to Xamarin.  That code only runs once anyway.  Because I made the variable static with a value, the first time you access that property, the dictionary is created.  When you actually call GetEntityList, it just does a super-fast dictionary lookup against the dictionary stored in the static variable.